# Vertical code block delimiters in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse

Is it possible to enable vertical bars delimiting code blocks in eclipse ?

Comment: what do you mean , what vertical bars delimiting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referencing to [bug 84878](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=84878) about "Draw vertical lines in control flow statements", then no, it isn't possible yet.

> In order to help reading complex algorithm, one could imagine having some graphical connections in between constructs (remember when we learned algorithmic at school).

```
if (...) {
|  if (...) {
|  |
|  }
} else {
|
|
}
```

> I would imagine a thin line directly in the code, anchored on left side of control flow keyword, and t would only look nice if correctly indented